# Prove an inequality with ODE's

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I need to prove that $\int_0^1 (u(x))^2 dx \leq \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 (f(x))^2dx$ knowing that u solves the ODE $-u''(x) + u'(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in (0;1)$, and $u\in C_0^2((0;1))$ (u is $C^2$ and $u(0)=u(1)=0$).
I tried two methods but I can't conclude... First I showed that $\int_0^1 u^2(x)dx \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u'(x)^2dx$ and then I used the PDE so $u' = u'' + f$ and $u''= f - u'$, put it in the integral : $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(x)^2 + u''(x)(2f(x) + u''(x))dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x)^2  + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1u'(x)^2dx$ but then I start to run around in circles again.
I also to tried to do something more direct and using integration by parts $\int_0^1 u^2(x)dx = [ (\int_0^xu(t)dt)u(x))]_0^1 - \int_0^1 u'(x)\int_0^x u(t)dtdx$ and then to develop with the ODE by same problem. Someone have an idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: It is an ODE, not a PDE!

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy, do you have an idea maybe?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First show that

$$\int_0^1 u'(x)^2 \, dx = \int_0^1 u(x) f(x) \, dx$$

and apply the inequality you have proven and Young's inequality.

Comment: what kind of Young Inequality do you use? Because you have to use it with two non-negative elements, but here $f$ and $u$ may be negative

Comment: You can apply the Triangle Inequality for integrals first, i.e. $\big| \int_a^b u(x) f(x) \, dx \big| \leq \int_a^b  |u(x)f(x)| \, dx$.